# How to avoid child div inheriting parent div class

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, material-design

I am trying to make a dashboard to represent a few charts and some numbers. I have a parent div which has a class for it. Inside this div their are divs for charts and numbers. Now if the div for charts inherits the class from the parent that is fine considering the size of the charts. However the divs which display number should be of smaller size and I have applied another class for it. But the divs for numbers always take the parents div style . Is their a way the child divs would not take the parents div class.
Below are the images on how I am getting it now and how I am trying to get to.

CURRENTLY :
[image]

HOW IT SHOULD BE:

[image]

Below is the code on how it is currently.

```html
<div class="col-md-6 " style=" padding-bottom: 15px;" ng-repeat="obj in tab" ng-include="'chartstemplate'">


  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div ng-if="charts_type =='Number'" class="block" style=" padding-bottom: 30px;font-size: 45px;font-weight: 700; margin-right: -70px;">
      <!-- <div  ng-if="charts_type =='Number'" style=" height: 70px;font-size: 45px;margin-top: 30px;font-weight: 700;margin-left:180px; width: 16.66667% !important;">-->
      <dash-board ng-if="obj.chart_data" chart-data="obj.chart_data" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="svg-container" ng-if="charts_type =='Bar'" style="width: 440px; height: 430px;">
    <bars-chart ng-if="obj.chart_data" chart-data="obj.chart_data" />
  </div>
  <div class="svg-container" ng-if="charts_type =='Bar'" style="width: 440px; height: 430px;">
    <bars-chart ng-if="obj.chart_data" chart-data="obj.chart_data" />
  </div>
  <div class="svg-container" ng-if="charts_type =='Bar'" style="width: 440px; height: 430px;">
    <bars-chart ng-if="obj.chart_data" chart-data="obj.chart_data" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Consider doing this in CSS Grid instead - that's a native CSS spec designed for this exact type of layout.

Answer (score 0):

Either specifically override the inherited propert, or look into the :not() pseudo selector

Comment: How can you do a :not() for a div with bootstrap classes

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your column structure. I can show you how your structure can be -

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 *charts*
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            *number*
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            *number*
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            *number*
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            *number*
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```